# C++ program threading concepts

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am attempting to write what should be a fairly simple C++ program. It was three parts:

1. Serial client: should poll a serial server continuously and save the received values in a table, has an infinite for loop to continue polling the serial server
2. Logging: write the current table values to a .csv file with a timestamp every few seconds
3. Menu: Simple command line menu to start/stop the server and exit the program

I have tried to use pthread and boost::thread to make this three functions occur simultaneously but haven't had much luck.

Can anyone provide me with a bit of direction on all this, I'm new to threading, and maybe threading isn't even the right way to go here.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code you did try so people can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: It should work with `pthreads` . Just post the parts of code where you feel it goes wrong. [Psst! Be fast before you get closed]

Comment: boost is really not necessary for creating a thread. Why don't you use an API for creating a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you are asking:

```
boost::mutex mtx;

void poll_thread()
{
    while(!done) {
        poll_for_data();
        if(data_received) {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mtx);
            //write data to table
        }
    }
}

void log_thread()
{
    while(!done) {
        sleep(1);
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mtx);
        //log table to csv file...
    }
}

int main()
{
    //create and start the polling and logging thread
    boost::thread th1(&poll_thread);
    boost::thread th2(&log_thread);

    //run the menu
    while(!done) {
        //...
    }

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The mutex is necessary to avoid accessing the table simultaneously in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common senario.

Typically your application will have a main thread that will:

1. Setup the serial connection.
2. Drive the menu (user input etc)

The serial connection will then have a listen thread.  As data is received on the serial connection it will fire a data received event that will be handled by the main app.  Typically you'd use one of many available library objects at your disposal to simplify serial port communication.  This will take the work out of setting up and managing the listening thread your self.  In that case you just wire your app event handler to serial port handler objects DataReceived event.  In C++ world the most likely canditate here would be [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  There is also a decent implimentation of serial port communication object with a good supporting article here: [CodeProject Serial library for C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C).

If the event handler (called on serial listen thread) and main app thread are both acessing some shared data (the data table you mention) then you will need to protect access to this object with synchronization primatives (e.g CriticalSection, Mutex, etc) to avoic concurrent access (one thread (serial listen thread) writing or adding to the data structure while the other thread (main app thread) is reading or pulling from it).